# How to fix long running scripts?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, leaflet

I'm working on building a leaflet map with a bit of data. Overall, I will have any where between 0 and 18000 marker points on the map at any point in time.

Necessary code to understand what I am attempting to achieve:

```
var ds = L.markerClusterGroup({
                                disableClusteringAtZoom: 9,
                                maxClusterRadius: 120,
                                chunkedLoading: true,
                                iconCreateFunction: iconCreate
                            });

window.onload = function(){
    map = L.map('map', {
        layers: [baseLayer, ds],
        worldCopyJump: true,
        minZoom: 3,
        inertiaMaxSpeed: 300
    }).setView([lat, lng], zoom);

    callAjax("/ajax/markers1.php", markers); // 4220 rows

    // callAjax("/ajax/markers2.php", markers); // ~14000 rows
}

function callAjax(url, cb, options){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        opts  = options || {};


    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        ajaxCheck(xhttp, cb, opts);
    }

    xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
}

function markers(xhttp){                    
    var dJson = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

    for(var d = 0;d < dJson.length;d++){
        addMarker(dJson[d]);
    }
}

function addMarker(d){                
    L.marker([d.lat, d.lng], {
                id: d.id
            })
     .addTo(ds);
}
```

The above code grabs a JSON request from the specified URL and loops through the return to add the markers to the cluster group that is already tied to the map. In Chrome 49.0.2623.112 m it takes the first AJAX response to return after 8 seconds and another 3 to 5 seconds to load all the markers.

In IE 11 I get long running script. There are 4220 records in the first marker run. I have limited the loop to run only 100 times and it still gets long running scripts. Making it only output 1 marker works, but I need all 4220 (and later 14000).

I have found different places where "long running scripts" have been posted, but each ends up saying "Make your code better". For the task I'm attempting to accomplish my code feels to be perfect.

What am I missing on controlling IE so that this code can successfully run and eventually add all 18000+ markers on this map?

Comment: Interesting. I am currently generating an HTML table form data, and once it reaches a couple of hundred rows Internet Explorer takes a REALLY long time to compute the table as well. Would like to know if there is a solution to this kind of behaviour, too.

Comment: To be honest, having that many marker points on a map simultaneously is always going to cause performance issues. For a system I worked on a couple of years ago that needed to deal with potentially hundreds of thousands of points, we used a pre-generated heatmap overlay graphic instead of marker points for wider zoom levels, and only showed actual markers when there map was zoomed in to a level where there were <1000 markers in the window area. We also added and removed markers dynamically as the user scrolled to keep the total number of markers in memory below a certain threshold (5000, IIRC)

Comment: Yea. Clustering is my current attempt to lower performance issues. It is working really well, but currently just adding markers is being a pain. I'm exploring Ivan's recommendation, but beta doesn't seem to be stable at this time.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few factors that came into play with this question. The first one was that Leaflet was not the primary issue, but instead duplication of (seemingly) unnecessary code.

IE can run ~5 million lines of Javascript before it decides to fail out (unedited settings). One flaw in this logic is that it seems to save the number of lines ran even if there is a period of wait between scripts. The only way to reset this number (harshly) is a setTimeout. This is a complete cop out. Do not get disheartened if you have to do this, but if you have scripts that loop multiple times and need it to work in IE then you're most likely going to need to add a setTimeout.

I did find recommendations for timeout time, but 50ms seems to be OK. Other recommendations was not to set it as the default time in the browser should suffice. However, some browsers have it set to 400ms which is nearly half a second long... That doesn't seem reasonable to me. So 50ms it is. No issues so far.

I guess "make your code better" is all this really can ever be. Or just get rid of IE. Just saying.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [profiling tools in your web browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Performance) to see what is eating all that time.

In your case, I bet it'll be calls to `addEventListener` on `dblclick` - in other words, [Leaflet bug 3972](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3972) and [Leaflet bug 4357](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4357), and the short answer is "Upgrade from Leaflet 0.7.x to Leaflet 1.0.0-beta".

Comment: Is there a place you would recommend seeing 20k+ markers added to a leaflet map? I'm not convinced these issues are similar to what i'm experiencing at this time. I will read into them and see if I can safely update to 1.0.0.

Comment: Yea... beta breaks my whole map... I'll look into it, but it is kinda disappointing no fix has been made to the "Stable" version...

Comment: This is a very poor answer to a known issue with leaflet. I can't prove this will solve my issue, but it for sure has caused more issues.